# unable to get the value of enumerator in Play 2.5 websocktes

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.streams._
import akka.stream._
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.actor.PoisonPill
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.stream.Materializer
import play.api.cache._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject() (cache:CacheApi) (implicit actorSystem:ActorSystem , materializer:Materializer) extends Controller {


  def validate(receivedMsg:JsValue,outChannel:Concurrent.Channel[JsValue], privateChannel:Concurrent.Channel[JsValue],outEnumerator:Enumerator[JsValue],privateEnumerator:Enumerator[JsValue]) = {

    val user_key = (receivedMsg \ "username").get
    val username = user_key.toString().stripSuffix("\"").stripPrefix("\"")

    val validate_user :Option[String] = cache.get[String](username)

        val valid_result = validate_user.toString()

        if(valid_result.equals("None")) {
          //cache is not set
         // println(valid_result)
          //add user
          cache.set(username,username)
          Ok.withSession(username->username)

          //notify all users
          val successMsg = Json.parse("""{"username":"Server","message":"A new user has been connected"}""") 

          outChannel.push(successMsg)
          (outEnumerator)


        }
        else{
          //cache is already set 
          //send error msg to new user 

           val errorMsg = Json.parse("""{"username":"Server","message":"This username is already taken"}""") 



          // val (privateEnumerator,privateChannel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]
           privateChannel.push(errorMsg)

           (privateEnumerator)


        }




  }


 val (outEnumerator,outChannel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]; //public stuff

  def socket = WebSocket.using[JsValue] {


  request => {



   val (privateEnumerator,privateChannel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]

   var enumerator = privateEnumerator
    var ret = 1;
    val inIteratee: Iteratee[JsValue, Unit] = Iteratee.foreach[JsValue](receivedMsg => {



    enumerator = validate(receivedMsg,outChannel,privateChannel,outEnumerator,privateEnumerator) 



    })

    (inIteratee, enumerator)
  }
}


}
```

I am new to scala and Play webSockets . I am working in play 2.5.3. Above depending upon the situation , i am trying to get the enumerator of private channel or public channel(i.e. for all connected users). But even if it returns it correctly, i couldn't get it in here **(iteratee,enumerator)**. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The second answer for this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576405/broadcasting-messages-in-play-framework-websockets/24628002#24628002) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Second answer of this post ([Broadcasting messages in Play Framework WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576405/broadcasting-messages-in-play-framework-websockets/24628002#24628002)) does the same thing.

Create an actor say `UserManagerActor` who sole purpose is to manage the users and maintain them.

`UserManagerActor` calls broadcast.

`val (enumerator, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]`.

`channel` helps in broadcasting the messages to all the users can once using the `push` method.

Now the actor can manage state of the users in a Map

`val users = Map[String, (Enumerator[String],Channel[String])]()`

Ensure the actor is killed once all users get disconnected.

Use `Iteratee` to know is the user is disconnected

Also remove disconnected users to keep the size of the Map manageable.